# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы после ввода значения в input(), это не отобразилось в консоли?

Tags: python, консоль, ввод, int

```
    start_ai_human = int(input('Вы будете играть с другом или с компьютером? [1 - Друг|2 - Компьютер]: '))
    if start_ai_human == 1:
        player1 = int(input('Игрок 1 выберает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
        player2 = int(input('Игрок 2 выберает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Камень!...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Ножницы!...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Бумага!...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Раз!...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Два!...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Три!')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('---------------------------')
        if player1 == 1:
            player1 = 'Камень'
        elif player1 == 2:
            player1 = 'Ножницы'
        elif player1 == 3:
            player1 = 'Бумага'
        if player2 == 1:
            player2 = 'Камень'
        elif player2 == 2:
            player2 = 'Ножницы'
        elif player2 == 3:
            player2 = 'Бумага'
```

Речь идет об:

```
player1 = int(input('Игрок 1 выбирает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
player2 = int(input('Игрок 2 выбирает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
```

Это фрагмент кода из программы "камень ножницы бумага", и желательно, чтобы после ввода значения *(1, 2 ,3)* это не отображалось в консоли.

Другими словами, я ввожу значение и после нажатия Enter это не появилось бы в консоли.

Я бы попробовал реализовать это сам, но не знаю как, и в интернете не было ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `getpass`:

```py
import time
from getpass import getpass


start_ai_human = int(input('Вы будете играть с другом или с компьютером? [1 - Друг|2 - Компьютер]: '))
if start_ai_human == 1:
    player1 = int(getpass('Игрок 1 выберает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
    player2 = int(getpass('Игрок 2 выберает предмет: 1 - Камень, 2 - ножницы, 3 - бумага: '))
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Камень!...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Ножницы!...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Бумага!...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Раз!...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Два!...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Три!')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('---------------------------')
    if player1 == 1:
        player1 = 'Камень'
    elif player1 == 2:
        player1 = 'Ножницы'
    elif player1 == 3:
        player1 = 'Бумага'
    if player2 == 1:
        player2 = 'Камень'
    elif player2 == 2:
        player2 = 'Ножницы'
    elif player2 == 3:
        player2 = 'Бумага'
```